# Verifying CDN Caching from a POP

Tags: angular, azure, akamai, azure-cdn

Our front-end team recently decided that it would be a good idea to serve our front-end Angular application, through a CDN. Yesterday, I was able to build my application and have its static assets served through a CDN, which means that I had a proof of concept to show to my colleagues.

However, our origin server is located in the **East US** region and so I would not suspect that performance for me (my computer is also located in the same region) to improve.

I decided to spin up a VM, using Azure, and deploy it in the **West US** region and try and hit my public front-end (which has the CDN configured) inside of that VM.

If I wanted to verify that I am getting assets from a POP closer to the West US region and not still through the East US region, how could I do this? I tried using `tracert` from within the VM but because Azure blocks ICMP, I am unable to do so.

Are there any other ways of verifying that my CDN is working properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you could use `Curl -vos CDNendpoint` to check the `server` value. Usually, this represents a city with an [IATA Location Identifier code](https://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/IATA_Codes/IATA_Code_D.htm). From the screenshot below, I received the server code `DAA` which represents the USA in the location Identifier. If you access the endpoint URL the first time, it will get the contents from the origin server. You could access the endpoint again to get it from a POP server. Cache is working when you see `x-cache` value `HIT`. I'm using Premium Verizon CDN.

[image]